# JetBrains Toolbox error: Failed to prepare Directory. Unable to create version folder

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

**Note:**

I'm sure there is a better way of fixing this. I just thought I would put it out there to save someone some frustration.

I'm no expert, just trying to be helpful.

**Problem:**

When using JetBrains toolbox on an Ubuntu-based Linux distribution, the  tool gives me an error:

`Failed to prepare Directory. Unable to create version folder: /home/solomon/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/[a version number]`

**Details:**

- I've only come across it with Ubuntu-based Linux distributions.
- Sometimes it doesn't happen when trying to install a new IDE after running the application as a super user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also just ran into this, and it turns out that the `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox` was set to root ownership. I must have used `sudo` when running it originally.

The following fixed it:

`sudo chown -R <username>:<username> ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox`

Comment: I tried that and did not work.
So I tried `rm -r ~/.local/share/JetBrains` and I ran JetBrains again and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Can fix by adding read and write priveleges to the directory where it's installed:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /home/[username]/.local/share/JetBrains`

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, enountered the same issue. This worked for me,

**`sudo chown -R <username>:<username> ~/.local/share/JetBrains`**

Answer (score 1):

For mac users:

```
sudo chown -R user:group /usr/local/jetbrains-cli/
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, it was the following:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/apps
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin/apps
```